# How to deal with "Warning MVC1004 Property on type '' has the same name as parameter '"?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-binding

I am trying to add some validation logic on a query string parameter but keep stumbling on this warning.

> Warning MVC1004 Property on type 'CountryCode' has the same name as parameter 'countrycode'. This may result in incorrect model binding.Consider renaming the parameter or using a model binding attribute to override the name.

With a reference to [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes)

As a result: the model binding fails.

---

#### Let me show you the case:

Basically I am trying to apply validation logic to a `HttpGet` query string parameter, which simple type is `string`.

So, my initial thought was to wrap the parameter in a class and add some implicit conversions to make it easy to use.

The type is a `CountryCode`, and, as said, the simple underlying type is `string`.

The idea is to call it like this:

> http://example.org?countryCode=EU

Here is the CountryCode:

```
public class CountryCode
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "countryCode")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{2}$")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    
    public static implicit operator string(CountryCode countryCode)
    {
        return countryCode.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator CountryCode(string countryCode)
    {
        return new CountryCode()
        {
            Value = countryCode
        };
    }
}
```

So, the next step is to use it in a controller:

```
public IActionResult Get(CountryCode countryCode)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest("list errors");
    //logic here
    return Ok();
}
```

Actually this looked very promising, if it wasn't for the warning to pop up and the actual binding does not succeed resulting in a `null` for Value.

---

#### But,

then, if I either change the name of the parameter used in the action:

```
public IActionResult Get(CountryCode foo)
```

**or** change the name in the `FromQuery` attribute:

```
[FromQuery(Name = "foo")]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

Everything works fine.

---

Now, my goal is to use `countryCode` as well as for the query string parameter name as for the C# method parameter name, keep the attribute validation and keep the implicit cast to string.

Is there a way to do that?

I have tried a couple of things:

- fiddled with the names
- tried to use `[BindAttribute]`, `[FromQuery]`, `[ModelBinderAttribute]`
- renamed `Value` to an actual name
- used a `snake_case` for `country_code` (it works) but will not help me with properties like `day` (I am trying to use this as pattern)
- a custom model binder (I hope I don't need to)
- some more

but I did not avail. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are already binding the property via `FromQuery` there is no need for the parameter name to be `countryCode`. That is what is causing the binding conflict.

changing the name of the parameter used in the action is enough as you have already seen

```
public IActionResult Get(CountryCode model) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest("list errors");
    //logic here
    return Ok();
}
```

The `[FromQuery(Name = "countryCode")]` in the model will be picked up picked up by the model binder and your model will be populated by design.

Comment: Yes, well the thing is; I want other people to adapt to this pattern as well. So ideally the name of the action methods parameter should not break thinks, especially since it's the most natural name to pick.